# Adwords Test Account: [QuotaCheckError.INCOMPLETE_SIGNUP @ ; trigger:'<null>']

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Trying to connect to the Google AdWords API and when running addCampaigns.php from the PHP API examples, I get the following error:

An error has occurred: [QuotaCheckError.INCOMPLETE_SIGNUP @ ; trigger:'']

Which is the problem? Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: You should check this link: [Common Errors - AdWords API — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/common-errors#QuotaCheckError)

Answer (score 0):

The error usually indicates that you have not yet accepted the terms and conditions and/or not filled in any billing information for the MCC account where you have created your API token. You can check the status of your token in the Adwords web interface under `My account` → `Adwords API Center`.